# unable to check that a spied method was called in Mockito

Tags: mockito

I have a `signout` method which calls another class' `discard` method. I want to test that when `signout` is called, then `discard` is called once. I am trying to `spy` on `AuthenticatorService` and then check that its `discard` method was called but I get error

```
Wanted but not invoked:
fakeJWTAuthenticatorService.discard(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    <any>
);
```

The method to test is

```
def signOutUser = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>

    silhouette.env.authenticatorService.discard(request.authenticator, Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess(messagesApi("success.signoutSuccessful")(langs.availables(0)))))) //I want to test that `discard` is called once
  }
```

The test case I have written is

```
  "signOutUser" should {
    "should be called when signout request is received" in {
      val testEnv = new TestEnv(components = components)

      val request = FakeRequest("POST", "ws/users/user-signout").withAuthenticator(testEnv.loginInfo)(testEnv.fakeEnv)
      //spying calls the real method.
      val authenticatorServiceSpy = Mockito.spy(testEnv.fakeSilhouette.env.authenticatorService)
      val response = testEnv.controller.signOutUser(request)
      val responseBody = contentAsJson(response)
      println(s"response is ${responseBody}")
      val result = (responseBody \ "result").get.as[String]
      val message = (responseBody \ "additional-info").get.as[String]

      result mustBe "success"
      verify(authenticatorServiceSpy,times(1)).discard(ArgumentMatchers.any[JWTAuthenticator],ArgumentMatchers.any())(ArgumentMatchers.any())
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the object returned by testEnv.fakeSilhouette.env.authenticatorService itself be a mock?  That would be the ideal way to handle this.  If you are testing class A, you want to use mocks to eliminate dependencies on other class (such as class B) so that you can focus your test just on A's code.  In this case you are testing the signout method, and it seems to depend on the authenticator service.  Can you inject this dependency so that the authenticator service that the signout method uses is a mock instead of a spy?